# What is the architecture behind virtualized browsers?

Tags: virtualization, remote-desktop

Virtualized browser apps such as [Puffin Browser](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cloudmosa.puffinFree) and [Flashfox](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=mobi.browser.flashfox) allow mobile devices to playback and interact with Flash and other restricted content.

To my understanding, this is achieved through an RDP-like protocol which effectively means a browser is launched on a cloud server and streamed back to the client app.

However, my confusion comes with my limited use of remote desktop software. Typically, opening an RDP/VNC connection will launch a full-experience shell, sharing the entirety of the GUI including the desktop, menus and application chrome. Instead, only the viewport of a browser session should be shared.

Additionally, how is the user sandboxed to the browser viewport? How are they prevented from right-clicking, opening new tabs, invoking application menus, tabbing to other applications or launching the Start menu, etc.?

I'm not expecting a full break-down of the software and configuration required to achieve this; I'm happy to investigate that myself. I would simply appreciate some pointers to guide me in the right direction.